# How to generate reports of Playwright tests in Jenkins

Tags: typescript, jenkins, playwright

I am a beginner with Jenkins and would like to know if there is any simple solution to generate HTML reports (or any other reports) of Playwright tests. My Jenkinsfile looks like that:

```
pipeline {
  agent { 
    docker { 
      image 'mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.17.2-focal'
    } 
  }
  stages {
    stage('install playwright') {
      steps {
        sh '''
          npm i -D @playwright/test
          npx playwright install
        '''
      }
    }
    stage('test') {
      steps {
        sh '''
          npx playwright test jenkins-homepage.spec.ts
        '''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Looking at the result just from Console Output in Jenkins, failed tests look very unclear: [image: example] Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Playwright generates an HTML report by default, just use npx playwright show-report once your test run is completed. Jenkins also can do it for you. ANother way is to integrate with allure reporter.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the playwright report with archiveArtifacts. Then send it via email or view it directly in Jenkins.